# Can't get JSON response using PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am learning to create an API to return JSON for my Android App.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

I am not getting the JSON response if i add this line

`$product["Area"] = $row["Area"];`

If i remove the Above line from the below file. Then i am getting the response.

I have even checked the DB. I can't figure it why it happens.

Thanks in Advance

**This is my PHP File** (get_all_products)

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shelter") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $product["Timestamp"] = $row["Timestamp"];
        $product["Accomodation"] = $row["Accomodation"];
        $product["Area"] = $row["Area"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: you are following a bad tutorial from 3 years ago that uses deprecated tools and apis.

Comment: What does print_r($product) show?

Comment: @VIDesignz Array ( [ID] => 641 [Timestamp] => 03-12-2015 15:24 [Accomodation] => many [Area] => Vadapalani Forum Mall ) 1

Comment: @njzk2 Please suggest me a nice Tutorial for the same...

Comment: This tutorial is just a few weeks old: http://kb4dev.com/article/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql-and-json

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *FROM Shelter
```

it looks a bit odd, shouldn`t it be

```
SELECT * FROM Shelter
```

also see if you have a column Area in shelter table and has valid data in it.

Comment: I have changed it like this SELECT * FROM shelter. 
Check the DB here http://i.imgur.com/Cr4VmGW.png